# How to avoid wordpress permalink rules to inherit in a sub-folder

Tags: htaccess

I have WordPress installation on the root of a website, I need to install another application on a sub-folder but that application got its own set of rules for URLs on its .htaccess file, my problem is that WordPress takes the control, and when I try to go to a URL on that sub-folder WordPress would just show me an 404 error.

I need the sub-folder app to work ignoring WordPress rules completely, or the opposite, WordPress to ignore the application on that sub-folder and leave it work on its own.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I think I found a solution, on the inside folder .htaccess file I added the base url with the sub-folder on it, and now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

`RewriteRules none` in that directory's `.htaccess` file should stop mod_rewrite from inheriting Wordpress' rewrite rules.